# Set Jenkins parameters from AWS Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to get environment variables from AWS Parameter Store for Jenkins CI/CD pipeline. I have assigned IAM role to this instance, so no credentials are required to be passed.
This is my parameter

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "Test",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "Hello World",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1639400445.755,
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:########:#########:parameter/Test",
            "DataType": "text"
        }
    ],
    "InvalidParameters": []
}
```

I have installed **AWS Parameter Store Build Wrapper** plug-in and using **withAWSParameterStore** method to capture the value.

This is how I am trying

```
val = withAWSParameterStore(namePrefixes: "Test", regionName: '#######'){}
echo val
```

Variable var returns null.

How do I capture the value "Hello World" here.

Comment: The parameters will be available inside the  `withAWSParameterStore` block. Try something like `withAWSParameterStore(namePrefixes: "Test", regionName: '###'){ echo "My parameter value is ${Test}"}`

Comment: @NoamHelmer It isn't identifying param Test. Got error 
```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Test for class: groovy.lang.Binding ```

Comment: Try `env.Test`, and if it is not working you have an issue with the parameters given to the `withAWSParameterStore` keyword.

Comment: @NoamHelmer tried as ```env.TEST``` and ```${env.TEST}``` . All gives null

Comment: @NoamHelmer I tried that too. I tried Upper case TEST as per in the doc
Each AWS Parameter Store parameter name is converted to uppercase and any non-numeric characters are converted to underscores. For example, the parameter name my-param1 with value my-value1 would become the environment variable MY_PARAM1=my-value1.

Comment: The issue was with credentials, I had to explicitly pass the credentials, and the IAM role assigned to Jenkins Server didn't help here. @NoamHelmer

Comment: @NoamHelmer thank you for providing the syntax. Once the credential part was done, it worked seemlessly.

Comment: Glad to hear (or read )! You can post as answer what eventually worked for you.

Comment: @NoamHelmer thank you for providing the syntax. Once the credential part was done, it worked seamlessly.
Below three syntax gave me the desired output.
```echo "${env.Test}"
echo "${env.TEST}"
echo TEST ```


method block



```withAWSParameterStore(credentialsId: 'myjenkins-id', namePrefixes: 'Test', naming: 'null', regionName: 'ap-south-1') {
                        echo "${env.Test}"
                        echo "${env.TEST}"
                        echo TEST}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM role assigned to EC2 instance where Jenkins is running doesn't help. We still need to create a credential in Jenkins with IAM Access and Secret key.
In order to capture the data, you may follow something like the below:

````
withAWSParameterStore(credentialsId: 'myjenkins-id', 
namePrefixes: 'Test', 
regionName: '########') { 
         echo "${env.Test}" 
         echo "${env.TEST}" 
         echo TEST} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Performed below list as part of integration of AWS parameter store with jenkins.
1)AWS Parameter store build wrapper plugin installed on jenkins running on aws ec2 instance

2)Attached IAM Role with SSM policy(parameter store comes under) to the jenkins aws ec2 instance

3)created secret credentials to communicate with aws account on the jenkins

4)created one of the parameter with values and trying to retrieve the value from jenkins via pipeline as well freestyle jenkins job

5)jenkins is unable to make api calls to aws account

Note: able to make a call via aws cli and retrieve the values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeK0L.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O7PO.jpg)

Comment: @Haris, do you see anything similar as you had already worked on same issue.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or scripts, paste in your text so others can more easily find your answer and implement your proposed solutions.

Comment: @sivashankar It has been a while since I encountered the issue, and after finding the fix, I didn't have to revisit it. So unable to help. Please try the syntax I have used to capture the value and see.